# Counting specific object types in an ArrayList C#

Tags: c#, arraylist

how does one go about counting the amount of a specific object type in an ArrayList in C#?

More specifically, I have three subclasses of base class 'Letter', 'X', 'Y' and 'Z'. Various amounts of X, Y and Z objects have been created and added to an arraylist. I then need to count how many X objects are in that list. What's the best way of going about this?

Cheers for any help guys/gals.

Comment: Maybe using the `is` operator on each element?

Comment: Why is it an ArrayList instead of a List<Letter> ?

Comment: Harold is right -- using an ArrayList in this day and age is a bad code smell. Use a `List<T>` instead if you can.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can also use the [OfType<T> Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx):

```
int myCount = myArrayList.OfType<X>().Count()
```